# Using pagination with NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I would like to know how can I make a paginated table using `NSFetchedResultsController`. I would like each page to hold 20 entries, and to have a page index that lets me navigate between pages.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }


    [self getDataOptions];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Profile"];

     NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];

     NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Friends"];
     aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
     self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@" Error %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], error);
        abort();
     }

     return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: `setFetchOffset:`, `setFetchLimit:`

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 5**, you can do something like this:

**1** - Choose an `offset` and a `limit`:

```
var offset: Int = 0
var limit: Int = 20
```

**2** - Set the `NSFetchedRequest` with your **entityName** (mine is "Product") and `NSFetchedResultsController` with a cache name, for example: **CACHENAME**.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Product> = {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Product>(entityName: "Product")

  // Configure Fetch Request
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
  fetchRequest.fetchOffset = self.offset
  fetchRequest.fetchLimit = self.limit

  let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.shared.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "CACHENAME")
  fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
  return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

**3** - Perform fetch.

```
do {
  NSFetchedResultsController<Product>.deleteCache(withName: fetchedResultsController.cacheName)
  try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch {
  print("--->> Oops, perform fetch failed")
}
```

**4** - Load next information, just changing `offset` and `limit` the way you want, and performing fetch again.

```
func loadNext() {
  let lastLimit = self.limit + 3
  self.limit = lastLimit

  fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.fetchOffset = self.offset
  fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.fetchLimit = self.lastLimit
  do {
    NSFetchedResultsController<Product>.deleteCache(withName: fetchedResultsController.cacheName)
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
  } catch {
    print("--->> Oops, perform fetch failed")
  }
}
```

**Important: Clear cache every time you call `performFetch`**

Comment: Did exactly what you described but NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Methods are not called on changes. I can use reload data but I want smooth scrolling.

Comment: when user scroll to top of the tableview then I update  fetchOffset  and fetchLimit and again performFetch on fetchedResultsController but new data is not fetched.
fetchedResultsController have same number of objects as it loaded initially. what could be the reason?

Answer (score -1):

the results controller can fetch all (so it can form sections correctly)... your tableview where you see the data should be limited.

Comment: https://github.com/Daij-Djan/TwitterSearchExampleApp doesn't use a fetchedResultsController but should maybe help you (disclaimer: own code)

Comment: @downvoter: I dont oppose downvotes - i use them too but plz leave a comment at least

Comment: Your approach kills the idea of FRC. Whats the purpose of FRC if you are going to load all the data? For sections use transient properties. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/datesectiontitles/Introduction/Intro.html) Using pagination with FRC seems to be a headache, im still trying to find the optimal solution.

Comment: the FRC uses a faulted array so not everything is loaded. Just keep the UI from faulting it all in. on a 3g fetching 10000 sectioned! was < 1s. on a 3gs 0.0x -- the expensive thing is the UI that faults it in

Comment: just reading data shouldnt be the issue and using an offset and fetchLimit really kills the FRC :D